# iOS 11 Loading Images from HTTP with ATS

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, nsurl

Hi have the following code to download images from a web server. The request are HTTP so un secured.

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        var productImage = Utilities.GetEmptyImageBottle()
        if (entry.ImageName != nil || entry.ImageUrl != nil) {
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: entry.ImageUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!)!)

            if data != nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                productImage = image!
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.ProductImage.image = productImage
        }
    }
```

I also added the following in my info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Now my images don't load and I get the following error:

```
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
```

This is in Xcode 9 running iOS 11. On iOS 10 in Xcode 8, no problems.

What did I missed?

Comment: Besides the question, there's a lot wrong with your code.  Don't use `nil` checks, instead use `if let` statements.  Also, you should be loading web requests asynchronously with `NSURLSession.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of `NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL` is that there is no available protocol handler for the URL (maybe your URL string lacks 'http://' in the URL prefix?).

Comment: The problem is here: .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)

Answer (score 0):

```
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"
```

-1002 seems to be more of a problem with the URL (host name) than the http.

Answer (score 0):

Am not pretty sure if the issue is due to iOS 11 or Xcode 9 , but sounds like you need to apply this

.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)

on only the last part of the URL where you may find special characters . I tried it and it worked , applying it on the full url corrupts http: format to http%35 which is not a base for url , hence no retrieving with failure event of web view gets called . So apply it to only the part you of the url you may suspect it to contain special characters liek spaces ,,etc